# SQL: How to find the initial value, and the value at each row, by knowing the current value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, this is a weird one, and I will try to explain what I mean.

Let's say I know the current stock of an sku (at the moment):

```
select sku, sum(stock)
from stock
where sku = '1234'
group by sku
```

and then I have the sales for that sku:

```
select * 
from sales
where sku = '1234' and saleDate > SOME_DATE   <---- Get sales for a certain period
order by saleDate desc
```

**And I want to find what the stock level was, and what made it such down to a given date.**

So the result should look like this:

```
Current stock @ 21.06.2019 is 50     <---- I know this value

20.06.2019: stockStart = 53, sold = 3, stockEnd = 50   <---- I know the sales, don't know the stock
19.06.2019: stockStart = 58, sold = 5, stockEnd = 53   <---- I know the sales, don't know the stock
18.06.2019: stockStart = 60, sold = 2, stockEnd = 58   <---- I know the sales, don't know the stock
17.06.2019: stockStart = 68, sold = 8, stockEnd = 60   <---- I know the sales, don't know the stock

Initial stock @ 16.06.2019 was 68    <---- Don't know this value
```

What would the SQL query look like to get something like this, where I know the current stock, I know what was sold, but I want to find:

- The stock at each sales row.
- The final stock. (This is essentially the last row, stockStart column)

Comment: Mmm... ‘select * from stock_history where stock_name = your stock’.

Comment: So on a givenDate your stockStart should be currentStock + sum(sold) where saleDate >= givenDate. I don't know on wich DBMS you can perhaps make something with a recursive function

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: @mkRabbani SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this following query. Some inline and Sub query are there which may cause performance issue. But considering your requirement, I feel this following query will provide at least some guide line to you.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '20190619'

SELECT  saleDate Date,
Current_Stock + ISNULL(sold_from_today,0) stockStart,
Sold,
Current_Stock + ISNULL(sold_from_tomorrow,0) stockEnd 
FROM
(
    Select *,
    (select sku, sum(stock) from stock where sku = '1234') Current_Stock,
    --68 Current_Stock,
    (SELECT SUM(Sold) FROM sales B WHERE B.saleDate >= A.saleDate AND  B.saleDate  > @FromDate  AND B.sku = '1234') sold_from_tomorrow,
    (SELECT SUM(Sold) FROM sales B WHERE B.saleDate > A.saleDate AND  B.saleDate  > @FromDate AND B.sku = '1234') Usold_from_today
    from sales A
    where A.sku = '1234' and A.saleDate > @FromDate
)A
ORDER BY saleDate DESC
```

Comment: Damn, that looks convoluted as hell haha. I gave it a run and it seems to work. I have to wrap my head around it, it's a bit mind bendy. I will mark the answer later when I confirm it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but with a reversed logic. I edited the code to the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and I approved your Edit already. Nice to hear that the script helped.